# Anyone know how to set Notepad++ as default text editor for SAS, Stata and R?

Tags: r, sas, notepad++, stata

Anyone know how to set Notepad++ as default text editor for SAS, Stata and R?

I'm having the hardest time finding anything online (particularly for SAS). Looking for ability to run code from Notepad++ as well as setup color coding.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not set up an IDE? They (mostly) come with customizable __syntax coloring__ and plus handles source code better than a word editor.

Comment: Notepad++ does provide syntax coloring. It's a lot more than just a text editor, but probably isn't enough to act as an IDE.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/474079/141 could help

Comment: I think your question title is misleading.  You're not asking how to set it up to double-click open things (I hope) as that's not SO on topic; you're asking how to do syntax highlighting and execute code.

Comment: UltraEdit, by the way, is probably the easiest editor program to get to work with SAS (and I would guess others), although it's not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ is my favorite editor and I was in the same shoes as you are now.

I am assuming that you are in Windows (Notepad ++ doesn't exist in Mac, saddest thing for me)

Please follow the steps mentioned in the below webpage and do as the author says.

http://hafniumcity.com/notepad_color.php

Now for in-line editing , it may be not be the best choice for SAS. Although I haven't tried it much so not a good person to comment on it.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the response and link.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just go the GUI route:  right click, e.g., any `foo.R` file and select "Open with...", then pick Np++ and click the "always open this file type.." button.  Rinse, lather, repeat.

BTW, for `R`, if you don't already have it,  get "NppToR" , a little app which lets you execute code directly from the Npp window.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Carl. That might work if the R files were already written, but I'm thinking that I just want to open Notepad++, write some code, and run it. I'm not comfortable running in batch yet, so I tend to have my code window open, select lines and run. I'm in RStudio mostly.

Comment: NppToR sounds really helpful! Thanks! Do you know if there are similar apps which do same for Stata and SAS?

Comment: @mattjans  Sorry, I've never worked with those tools, so don't know of any interface apps.

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can either:

- manually edit the keys for the file type to set the value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FILE_TYPE\shell\edit\command` where `FILE_TYPE` is the appropriate one for each of the files extensions you wish to change *this is quite hard work* or
- you can use a program that does it for you such as the free [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)

In either case the **first** thing to do is to back up the registry.

I would seriously suggest looking into using one of the many, *some* ***free*** IDEs as they will automatically include the run from edit environment, syntax highlighting, code completion and, *in many cases,* debugging as well.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Steve. I use RStudio for my IDE, but I've been tempted to do all my coding in NP++ so I don't have to work in different IDEs for SAS, Stata, and R. That will probably require getting comfortable with batch submission to make it really efficient. I've started to play around with that, but not totally comfortable.